# Calling class functions of different forms

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have an application which includes the "main" form as well as four other forms (formA, formB, formC, formD). Each one of the four forms has a unique `class function execute()`.

Now, in formD, I put an edit box and a button. On the button's `OnClick` event, depending on which form's name I pass in the edit box, I want to run the appropriate class function.

I tried to implement this task by creating a `TDictionary` in which I add 3 pairs of values, but it didn't work.  Specifically I did the following:

```
unit FormDU;

interface

type
  TFormD = class(TForm)
  Edit1: TEdit;
  fcShapeBtn1: TfcShapeBtn;
  .............
  .............
public
  class function execute:boolean;
  ..........
  ..........
end;

var
  FormD: TFormD;
  MyList:TDictionary<string,TForm>;


implementation 

class function TFormD.execute:boolean;
  begin
    FormD:= TFormD.Create(nil);
    MyList:= TDictionary<string,TForm>.create;
    MyList.Add('FormA',TFormA);
    MyList.Add('FormB',TFormB);
    MyList.Add('FormC',TFormC);
    FormD.showmodal;
  end;

procedure TFormD.fcShapeBtn1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  // Here I check whether the text in Edit1 box has the value of one of the
  // keys that are included in the MyList dictionary and if yes I want to 
  // trigger the class function execute of the appropriate form...

  if MyList.ContainsKey(Edit1.text) then  // suppose that text= formA
      MyList.Items[Edit1.text].execute // which doesn't work.... 

  // I thought that the 'Items' method of the dictionary would return back 
  // to me the appropriate form type - which is connected to the specific 
  // key - and thus I could call each form's class function execute()
end;
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach:

1. your `TDictionary` is declared to hold `TForm` object pointers, but your code is trying to insert `TForm`-derived class types instead.  That will not compile.
2. Your Form classes do not derive from a common base class that has an `Execute()` method for them to override.  So you can't just retrieve a value from your `TDictionary` and call `Execute` directly. You would have to resort to using RTTI to find and invoke `Execute()` instead.

There are some possible ways to address this:

1. derive your Form classes from a common base class, and store derivatives of that base class in your `TDictionary`:

   ```
   unit FormBaseU;

   interface

   uses
     Forms;

   type
     TFormBase = class(TForm)
     public
       class function Execute: Boolean; virtual;
     end;

     TFormBaseClass = class of TFormBase;

   implementation

   class function TFormBase.Execute: Boolean;
   begin
     Result := False;
   end;

   end.
   ```

   ```
   unit FormDU;

   interface

   uses
     ..., FormBaseU;

   type
     TFormD = class(TFormBase)
       Edit1: TEdit;
       fcShapeBtn1: TfcShapeBtn;
       ...
     public
       class function Execute: Boolean; override;
       ...
     end;

   var
     FormD: TFormD;
     MyList: TDictionary<string, TFormBaseClass>;

   implementation 

   uses
     FormAU, FormBU, FormCU;

   class function TFormD.Execute: Boolean;
   begin
     MyList := TDictionary<string, TFormBaseClass>.Create;

     // make sure TFormA, TFormB, and TFormC all derive
     // from TFormBase and override Execute() ...
     MyList.Add('FormA', TFormA);
     MyList.Add('FormB', TFormB);
     MyList.Add('FormC', TFormC);

     FormD := TFormD.Create(nil);
     FormD.ShowModal;
     FormD.Free;
   end;

   procedure TFormD.fcShapeBtn1Click(Sender: TObject); 
   var
     FormClass: TFormBaseClass;
   begin
     if MyList.TryGetValue(Edit1.Text, FormClass) then
       FormClass.Execute;
   end;
   ```
2. do something similar but using an `interface` instead of a base class (this only works with objects, not class types, though):

   ```
   unit MyIntfU;

   interface

   type
     IMyIntf = interface
       ['{41BEF2B6-C27F-440E-A88B-9E5CF8840034}']
       function Execute: Boolean;
     end;

   implementation

   end.
   ```

   ```
   unit FormDU;

   interface

   uses
     ..., MyIntfU;

   type
     TFormD = class(TForm, MyIntf)
       Edit1: TEdit;
       fcShapeBtn1: TfcShapeBtn;
       ...
     public
       function Execute: Boolean;
       ...
     end;

   var
     FormD: TFormD;
     MyList: TDictionary<string, TForm>;

   implementation 

   uses
     FormAU, FormBU, FormCU;

   function TFormD.Execute: Boolean;
   begin
     MyList := TDictionary<string, TForm>.Create;

     // make sure TFormA, TFormB, and TFormC are all
     // instantiated beforehand and implement IMyIntf ...
     MyList.Add('FormA', FormA);
     MyList.Add('FormB', FormB);
     MyList.Add('FormC', FormC);

     FormD := TFormD.Create(nil);
     FormD.ShowModal;
     FormD.Free;
   end;

   procedure TFormD.fcShapeBtn1Click(Sender: TObject); 
   var
     Form: TForm;
     Intf: IMyIntf;
   begin
     if MyList.TryGetValue(Edit1.Text, Form) then
     begin
       if Supports(Form, IMyIntf, Intf) then
         Intf.Execute;
     end;
   end;
   ```
3. don't store classes/objects in your `TDictionary` at all, store the actual class methods instead:

   ```
   unit FormDU;

   interface

   uses
     ...;

   type
     TFormD = class(TForm)
       Edit1: TEdit;
       fcShapeBtn1: TfcShapeBtn;
       ...
     public
       class function Execute: Boolean;
       ...
     end;

     TMyClassMethod = function: Boolean of object;

   var
     FormD: TFormD;
     MyList: TDictionary<string, TMyClassMethod>;

   implementation 

   uses
     FormAU, FormBU, FormCU;

   class function TFormD.Execute: Boolean;
   begin
     MyList := TDictionary<string, TMyClassMethod>.Create;

     MyList.Add('FormA', TFormA.Execute);
     MyList.Add('FormB', TFormB.Execute);
     MyList.Add('FormC', TFormC.Execute);

     FormD := TFormD.Create(nil);
     FormD.ShowModal;
     FormD.Free;
   end;

   procedure TFormD.fcShapeBtn1Click(Sender: TObject); 
   var
     Meth: TMyClassMethod;
   begin
     if MyList.TryGetValue(Edit1.Text, Meth) then
       Meth;
   end;
   ```

Comment: Excelent answer.. i always thought that there is a way but couldn't find out. However i would never imagine that there are three different ways to fulfill this task ! 
Just a simple note.. as you mentioned the 2nd solution dictates the forms to have been already instantiated, which isn't always handy...
Also i would like to ask you: from your point of view which of the 3 ways would you suggest me to use and keep in mind as a basic rule ?